# Array first doesn't match at(0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Should `Array`'s `first` always return the same thing as `at(0)`? The order in which I call things affects the result. If I call the following code in a partial view in Rails:

```
<%= debug sections.at(0) %>
<%= debug sections.first %>
```

both of the outputs match. However if I switch the order to this:

```
<%= debug sections.first %>
<%= debug sections.at(0) %>
```

I get the last item in the array returned by `first`. Likewise if I do this:

```
<%= debug sections.last %>
<%= debug sections.first %>
<%= debug sections.at(0) %>
```

the first two entries match, and the last one matches. What's going on here?

Comment: Could you add what `sections` is, and what the outputs are that you get from each of your examples?

Comment: I would be nice to see data of `sessions` array

Comment: It's a big array of hashes. I'm trying to avoid plopping a massive wall of text in here. Let me try to get it down to two sections or something and put that in here. As an update, I've noticed that if I call `<%= sections.length %>' before the call, the problem goes away. It's like the array is in some "unfinished" state or something, and calling certain functions "fixes" it.

Comment: Try adding a dummy `sections = [0,1,2]` right before the first call and see if the strange behavior goes away.  If so, that points towards something weird in the data.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. `sections` printed as an array of sections in debug, but was actually an ActiveRecord::Relation that was kind of getting collapsed into an array. As a result, by calling `first` I was actually getting the result of `first` on the `Relation`, which for whatever reason was actually the section with the highest `id` (aka the "last" item). Converting my query to return `Section.where(...).all` instead of `Section.where(...)` fixed the problem. I can credit anybody who answers... although this is a pretty crazy problem that I feel shouldn't have happened!

Comment: it is better you could delete your post...As this is a localized issue..

Comment: Don't delete the question, convert your comment to an answer and accept your own answer. The behavior of ActiveRecord::Relation can be confusing at times so the question and answer are worthwhile.

Comment: @mu is too short: Agreed, this is a common trap with ORMs that accept array-like methods and syntax to resolve queries, it also occurs in Sequel.

Comment: Re: the `first` relation being the "last" relation: It's an underappreciated fact that result order is undefined (i.e. whatever's most convenient for the DB at any given moment) if an `ORDER BY` clause has not been provided. File that away; it **will** eventually bite you with most ORMs. Many NoSQL DBs and mappers behave the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. `sections` printed as an array of `sections` in debug, but was actually an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that was kind of getting collapsed into an array. As a result, by calling `first` I was actually getting the result of `first` on the `Relation`, which for whatever reason was actually the section with the highest id (aka the "last" item). Converting my query to return `Section.where(...).all` instead of `Section.where(...)` fixed the problem.

Comment: this seems like a bug